# How do I use .useDelimiter to exclude punctuation and numbers from a input file?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

For an assignment, I'm checking an input file against a binary search tree of dictionary words for spelling errors.

The issue I'm having is its returning numbers and stuff like "today," as misspelled words. I want to exclude all punctuation and numbers from the input.

I've come across the .useDelimiter() method but I have no idea what parameters to put into the brackets. Right now I'm just copy pasting anything i can find to see if it works.

This is my code so far for reading in the words.

```
reader = new Scanner(new File(testFile));
reader.useDelimiter("[.,:;()?!\"\\s\\d]+");
while (reader.hasNext()) {
test.add(reader.next());
```

when I do this, it does stop numbers and things like "today," from occurring but if i have a word like "5th", it says that "th" is misspelled.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First comment: there is not going to be an easy quick fix for this problem.

You're dealing with (evidently) English spelling -- no set of simple rules suitable for programming are going to do what you want to do.  So don't expect it.  You are evidently not satisfied with the occasional false positive, so it's going to be hard to do.

I think you'll have to give up using all those things as delimiters -- contractions aren't going to work either.  I think you're going to have to parse the file and get "words" using some broader definition, and then work on each word to determine what to pass through the spell-check and what not to.

You may need to look ahead in your scan as well -- single quotes can be used to quote words and phrases, or for contractions, or for possessives, and they should all be handled differently in your spell check.

Answer (score 0):

Please, correct if I'm wrong but arguments in `useDelimiter` should be separated with 'pipe' symbol. Like `useDelimiter("[|,|\\n")`

Comment: The brackets `[` and `]` are signify some thing of a set, or that it matches one of the characters between the brackets. No pipelines.